# How to upload a file (.xls/xlsx) extension in soapUI Pro?

Tags: soapui

I want to upload a file with `.xls` and `.xlsx` extension file to the **SOAP UI**. The content of the file is sent as a binary file and I have attached the document in the attachment tab at the bottom and the request to be sent from the `SOAP UI` is

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="M270.xls"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Since I just added the same lines in the request body, I see nothing happening. How should I add this in the request body? Also what all the mandatory things should be added? 
I am using SOAP UI Pro version.

Comment: Does any of this help? http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html#2-Attachments-and-Inline-Files

Comment: @SiKing - The example shown is for SOAP messages . Is it same for REST services?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @SiKing - Soap ui is not able to give any response